# WPF Databinding with Object Aggregation

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Suppose I have a class Person with the following properties and methods:

- `public string FirstName`
- `public string LastName`
- `public House CurrentHouse`
- `public void BuildHouse(string streetAddress)`

House is a separate class with some simple properties like street address.

When I first create a `Person` object, I databind a WPF window to it.  Person starts out with a `FirstName` and `LastName`, but their `CurrentHouse` is null.  (This is a stupid example but for the sake of argument let's say the person has to build a house before they can live in it.)  Databinding to `FirstName` and `LastName` works as expected.

Now let's say I want to move this person into a house.  The logic looks something like:

```
public void BuildHouse(string streetAddress)
{
    this.CurrentHouse = new House()
    {
        StreetAddress = streetAddress;
    };
}
```

My data context for the WPF window is this person object.  I have a label that shows the person's address (bound to `MyPerson.CurrentHouse.StreetAddress` with an `UpdateSourceTrigger` of `PropertyChanged`).  When I first show the screen the `CurrentHouse` object is null and the label is blank (expected behavior).  However when I call `BuildHouse("123 anywhere st")`, I expect the databound label to have its value changed to "123 anywhere st".

This is not what's happening and I'm starting to suspect it's because when the window is initially open, the CurrentHouse property for the databound `Person` object  is null.  Are my suspicions correct?  If so, what do I need to do to enable databinding on the label once the CurrentHouse object is no longer null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is not what's happening and I'm starting to suspect it's because when the window is initially open, the CurrentHouse property for the databound Person object is null. Are my suspicions correct? If so, what do I need to do to enable databinding on the label once the CurrentHouse object is no longer null?

This is possible, but it's more likely that your `Person` and `House` classes need to implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx).

Implementing this interface (correctly) is what allows WPF to know that a property on your object has changed (such as the new `House` being setup, or an address within the house changing, etc).